# Can you order posts from wp_query by two custom meta fields?

Tags: wp-query

I'm working on a site that lists events. Right now this query lists events by date:

```
$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'espresso_event',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 8,
                    'category_name' => 'homepage',
                    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'event_start_date',
                            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                            'compare' => '>=', // compares the event_start_date against today's date so we only display events that haven't happened yet
                            'type' => 'DATE'
                            )
                        ),
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );

        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query($args);
```

However, some events take place on the same date at different times and I need it to order posts first by date and then by a custom meta called event_start_time. Problem is, I'm at a loss on how to do that. wp_query doesn't seem capable of ordering by two custom meta.

Is this something I can even do?

Answer (score 1):

In pure `SQL` you can use comma separated strings to do what you want-- that is, something like `ORDER BY post_type,post_name,post_date`. However, `WP_QUERY` will not allow that kind of thing to pass through. There is a [rigid set of allowed values](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2348).

There are a couple of ways I can think of to do this.

You can "push" query vars to `WP_Query` just by adding them to your `$args`. ***Caveat*: I do not know if this is intended behavior. It may be a quirk in the code base.**

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 8,
  'orderby' => 'post_date,post_title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'myorderby' => 'post_date,post_name'
);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query($args);

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
  $wp_query->the_post();
  echo $post->post_title.'<br/>';
}
```

Add a filter on `posts_orderby`...

```
function posts_odb_filter_wpse_96900($odb) {
  global $wp_query;
  $myodb = $wp_query->get('myorderby');
  if (!empty($myodb)) {
    preg_match('/(ASC|DESC)$/',$odb,$dir);
    $odb = $myodb;
    if (!empty($dir[0])) {
      $odb .= ' '.$dir[0];
    }
  }
  return $odb;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','posts_odb_filter_wpse_96900');
```

... and you can order to your heart's content.

The (probably) more canonical way to do it is to check the query vars, or other information, and alter the query accordingly.

```
function posts_odb_filter_wpse_96900_v2($odb) {
  global $wp_query;
  if (is_front_page() && !is_main_query()) { // whatever conditions you need
    preg_match('/(ASC|DESC)$/',$odb,$dir);
    $odb .= ' post_date,post_name '.$dir[0];
  }
  return $odb;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','posts_odb_filter_wpse_96900_v2');
```

The drawback of the second method is that you have to create a filter for each query that you need to alter.